# Bigon criterion in dimension 3?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

The bigon criterion for surfaces says that if two simple closed curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$ embedded on a surface $\Sigma$ intersect in points $\{p_1,\dotsc,p_n\}$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be isotoped so that there are fewer points of intersection, then there is in fact a *bigon* on $\Sigma$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (a bigon between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is an embedded 2-dimensional disk $D$ with the boundary of $D$ partitioned into two arcs, one in $\alpha$ and the other in $\beta$, and otherwise $D$ is disjoint from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ — such a bigon then guides a simple to see isotopy that reduces the number of points of intersection between $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

I am interested in to what extent some generalizations of this hold in dimension 3.  The two possible cases I am interested in are:

1. We consider two surfaces $F_1$, $F_2$ embedded in a 3-manifold $M$.

Here a bigon would be a 3-dimensional embedded ball with interior disjoint from the surfaces and with boundary partitioned into two 2-dimensional disks — one in $F_1$ and the other in $F_2$.  Does the bigon criterion hold in this case?

2. We consider a knot $K$ and a surface $F$ embedded in a 3-manifold $M$.

Here a bigon would be an embedded disk with interior disjoint from the knot and surface and with boundary partitioned into an arc in $K$ and an arc in $F$.  Does the bigon criterion hold in this case?

Comment: For intersections between two surfaces, the number of points in the intersection is either zero or infinite, so how would you phrase your criterion? In any case, for pairs of surfaces there can't be a "bigon criterion"! Consider a genus 2 surface F_1 sitting in R^2 and a sphere F_2 which separates it into two pieces of genus 1. These surfaces are disjoinable, but there are no bigons in the sense you describe.

Comment: @JonnyEvans - I address your first question in my answer below.  Also, as your example shows, there is a need for a "side condition", namely incompressibility.  However, even without the side condition there are ways to phrase versions of the bigon condition to deal with your example.  Namely, we look for an isotopy supported on a three-ball (that may meet one of the two surfaces in a more complicated way).

Comment: @JonnyEvans Sorry I was not explicit -- I meant the number of curves in the intersection as Sam Nead interpreted it.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: While looking for the reference I thought I remembered, I realised that the criterion I gave for surfaces was wrong.  I have attempted to fix it.

---

One version of the bigon criterion for surfaces in a three-manifold is as follows: Suppose that $M$ is a compact, connected, closed, oriented three-manifold.  Suppose that $F$ and $G$ are compact, closed, connected, two-sided, incompressible surfaces in $M$ which intersect.  Suppose that $F$ and $G$ are transverse.  So their intersection is a finite collection of curves.  Let $|F \cap G|$ be the number of these curves.

If $F$ and $G$ can be made disjoint (via isotopy) then there is a there is a *product region* in $M - (F \cup G)$.  Here a product region is homeomorphic to a surface $X$ crossed with an open interval so that $X \times \{0\}$ lies in $F$ and $X \times \{1\}$ lies in $G$ and $(\partial X) \times (0,1)$ is mapped to some components of $F \cap G$. [The "flying saucer" (three-ball) region you mention is a special case of a product region where $X$ is a disk.]

Thus, there is an isotopy making $F$ and $G$ disjoint that monotonically decreases $|F \cap G|$.

---

On the other hand, when isotoping a knot off of a surface, sometimes the intersection number must go up before it goes down.  So I do not see a version of the bigon criterion here.  (The bigon you describe, meeting the knot and the surface each only in an arc of its boundary, does appear in various places.  Google "thin position of knots in the three-sphere" for example.)

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer! How would you go about proving your product region criterion? (Or is there a reference?)

Comment: Intriguing! What does this product region look like in the example I described in the comments? I can see three solid tori in the complement of the two surfaces, but the boundary of these solid tori is made up of a punctured torus in one surface and a disc in the other (intersecting along a loop).

Comment: @JonnyEvans - The genus two surface in your example is compressible.

Comment: @l.frost - I have realised that there is a problem with my initial statement.  I have tried to fix it.

Comment: @SamNead Ah! I missed that, thanks.

Comment: @SamNead Thank you for the update.  Do you possibly have a reference for the proof?

Comment: @l.frost - very sorry - I looked for (and found) the paper I was thinking of, and it seems to not contain the result. I think the proof is not so bad - take the preimage of $G$ under the isotopy making $F$ disjoint and use it to find the product regions.